# Macro to replace . in Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I have input data like: `the pixels are of 13.45 mm for the`

The output data after the macro should be like:

`the pixels are of 13,45 mm for the` in a Word document.

I'm trying the code below:

```
Sub RegexReplace1()

    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    On Error Resume Next

    RegEx.Global = True

    RegEx.Pattern = "([0-9]*).([0-9]*\s?mm)"

    ActiveDocument.Range = _
        RegEx.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range, ",")

End Sub
```

but it's replacing the entire thing with **.**

Answer (score 0):

First, since you need to match the `.`, you have to escape it with a `\` (a single `.` means "I want to match any character"):

```
([0-9]*)\.([0-9]*\s?mm)
```

Then, since you need to replace the `.`, you have to use the matching parenthesis around it, and not around the numbers:

```
[0-9]*(\.)[0-9]*\s?mm
```

Comment: @user145345 You should provide some example to make the case clearer. Edit your question to make it obvious to everyone.

Comment: modified the question , its more understandable now .

Comment: i have tried the parenthesis around but not working.

Comment: @user145345 Maybe you need to inspect what is captured before running the `RegEx.Replace` function, and paste your results. I cannot help you how to do that as I'm not a VB programmer. I can only help you on the regex part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$1,$2` as replacement string instead of just `,` to insert your capture groups before and after.

```
RegEx.Replace(ActiveDocument.Range, "$1,$2")
```

Also, like Morgan said, you need to escape the `.` I'd also suggest using `+` instead of `*`, to make sure you actually match a measurement value.

```
([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+\s?mm)
```